How to prevent access directly to .html files in URL without passing by a routing rule?

# Le serveur doit suivre les liens symboliques :
Options +FollowSymlinks

# Activation du module de réécriture d'URL :
RewriteEngine on

# Article sans numéro de page :
RewriteRule ^toto$   lalala.html [L]
RewriteRule ^(*).html$   404.html [L]

How to prevent access directly to .html files in the url ?
Here, /toto redirects me to 404.html whereas I want it to be redirected to lalala.html
I tried this answers here How to prevent a file from direct URL Access? but the same problem I have...
# Enable symbolic link following:
Options +FollowSymlinks

# Activate URL rewriting:
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect /toto to lalala.html:
RewriteRule ^toto$ lalala.html [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost.*$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^http://(www\.)?localhost/(.*)\.(html)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule . - [F]


You are still redirecting to HTML file. So does accessing /lalala.html should be prevented or not?

I want to allow access only typing /toto in the url to stop at lalala.html but not allowing to write explicitely lalala.html in the url

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond: "REQUEST_URI: The path component of the requested URI, such as /index.html." - so your attempt to match that against a full, absolute URL including protocol, really makes little sense.

@Justinas No, that is not a redirect, even if the comment claims so. But it actually is an internal rewrite.
